# How can connect with PLC on LabVIEW 2019 Linux version

Tags: linux, labview, plc

I installed LabVIEW 2019 on Linux CentOS 7. I want to connect LabVIEW by plc and get data. Before I am using opc on window but on Linux no existing this option.
I have any options to do work with PLCs?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add additional information like the type of PLC you'd like to communicate with. Also, have you made sure, that you have all LabVIEW-AddOns installed, that you have on the windows PC you are describing?

Comment: What PLC, what communication bus, what kind of data? OPC or OPC UA?